# ¿Cómo prevenir que desaparezcan las líneas de la propiedad gap de un contenedor grid al disminuir el zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid-layout

Creé un div contenedor con display: grid. Este tiene 16 elementos divididos 4 x 4. Le apliqué un gap de 1px, de forma que hay una separación tanto horizontal como vertical de 1 px. A los divs internos les apliqué un background blanco y al contenedor gris, de forma que las líneas del gap se muestren gris.
El problema surge al aumentar o disminuir el zoom, ya que al disminuir el zoom de la pantalla se desaparecen las líneas del gap. Al aumentar el zoom, pues unas lineas son más anchas que otras.

**Este es el código:**

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
 display: grid;
 background-color: #696969;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 width: 500px;
 height: 500px;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
 gap: 1px;
}

#container div {
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

Aquí una imagen con zoom normal al 100%
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí una imagen con zoom 120%
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí una imagen con zoom 80%
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tienen alguna solución para evitar esto les estaría agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Bien Luis. Hay que tener en cuenta que al disminuir el zoom de la página, todo el contenido es más chico. Los bordes tenés solamente a 1px. Y cuando disminuye el zoom, este desaparece y los div da la apariencia de juntarse.

Hay una solución para evitar la apariencia de que se peguen los div: con la medida de `.10em` hace que se mantenga una distancia según el zoom o según el estilo del contenido del padre (en este caso `#container`).

Dar un borde de `.09em` a los div, y un margen de `.10em` sería la solución.

Te sugiero que no uses píxeles en este caso sino, busca tu medida exacta con *em* la cuál te recomiendo.
Los navegadores usan como medida predeterminado `16px` en el body. Todos los textos normales y otros son de `16px`, (al menos que le dé tu propia medida), y esto equivale a `1em`. Pero `1em` es muy grande para un borde. Entonces disminuye con un punto antepuestos. Lo más próximo a `1px` sería `.09em` o `10em` (proeba y busca documentación sobre medidas **em**).

`1em` toma como base la medida `16px` del navegador en el `body`. Si se aumenta está medida en el `body`, también aumentarán todas las medidas `em` que exista en `body`, o viceversa.

```css
*,::before,::after {
 box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px; /* normal */
}

#container { 
 display: grid;
 background-color: #696969; 
 /*border: 1px solid red;*/
 padding: .10em;
 width: 500px; 
 height: 500px; 
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); 
 grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr); 
 gap: .10em;
} 

#container div { 
 margin: .10em .10em;
 border: .09em solid red;
 background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container"> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> </div>
```